# Correct way of using flatpickr to display, parse and save dates from/to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, flatpickr

I am working on a web app where one can create events.
The input fields for the date I would like to display with flatpickr.
Submitting an event and the according dates works but as I am trying to use it for editing existing dates I realize that I am missing something.

This is the function I am calling whenever creating a form:

```
function flatpickrInitialization(selector) {
        $(selector).flatpickr({
            dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:m",
            enableTime: true,
            minDate: "today",
            allowInput: true,
            formatDate: (date, time, format) => {
                return flatpickr.formatDate(date, time, format);
            },
            parseDate: (datestr, format) => {
                return flatpickr.formatDate(datestr, format);
            }
        });
    }
```

The date format used to store the dates is:

```
2022-08-17 12:00:00
```

The issue presents itself as the input fields not carrying the originally saved data. They show the input flatpickr mask with no values.
The hidden input fields created by the flatpickr script contain the saved values.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the selected time with javascript/jquery before sending it to your database

```js
let myFlatpickr = $(".flatpickr").flatpickr();
myFlatpickr.setDate(new Date());

$(document).on("click", "#load", function() {
  if (myFlatpickr.selectedDates[0] === undefined) return;
  let exportdate = myFlatpickr.selectedDates[0].getTime() / 1000;
  let db_str = databaseDateTime(myFlatpickr.selectedDates[0]);
  $("#result").html(`Timestamp: ${exportdate} <br> DateTime: ${db_str}`);
});

function databaseDateTime(d) {
  if (d != null) {
    d = new Date(d);
    return `${d.getFullYear()}-${String(d.getMonth()+1).padStart(2, "0")}-${String(d.getDate()).padStart(2, "0")} ` + String(d.getHours()).padStart(2, "0") + ":" + String(d.getMinutes()).padStart(2, "0") + ":" + String(d.getSeconds()).padStart(2, "0");
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.13/flatpickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.13/flatpickr.min.js"></script>

<input class="flatpickr" type="text">
<button id="load">GetDate</button>

<div id="result" style="margin-top: 25px"></div>
```